# Is there a way to tell the pasted content source in Word VBA?

Tags: vba, copy-paste

I know that MS Word allows users to choose how they want the paste to be depending on whether the pasting is from another software or same document or a different document. Is it possible to obtain that content source information from VBA? Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to get information like: "from where data comes (document, application, etc.)"?

Comment: Not really impossible in some limits, using API, but complicated. I know how to extract from clipboard in case of an Excel range [workbook name, worksheet name and range address (with some limitations in case of discontinuous ranges)]. Digging deeper, it may be possible to also identify some other sources, I think.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get information about a source of data in the clipboard, comming form outside application - sorry, **it's impossible**.

[MSDN wrote](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dataxchg/clipboard):

> The clipboard is a set of functions and messages that enable
> applications to transfer data. Because all applications have access to
> the clipboard, data can be easily transferred between applications or
> within an application.

The function to get such of information does NOT exist!

Note: that VBA can get some information via OleAutomation (COM):

> This overview does not describe how to copy and paste linked or
> embedded objects. *For information on these subjects, see the Component
> Object Model (COM) documentation*.

More information about VBA + Clipboard you can find here: [Visual Basic for Applications/Clipboard VBA](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_for_Applications/Clipboard_VBA)

Comment: I see. Yeah I'm just curious since MS Word knows that information so I assumed VBA can also get that information. I guess not then.